# send email with attachment file php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, email

While upload the file not send to email in php. here is my code.

```html
<form method="post" action="">
Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Upload File : <input type="file" name="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
  $image=$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $img=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     
$recipient = "test1@gmail.com";
 
    // Mail subject
    $subject = "contact by $name";
 
    // Mail content
    $email_content = " contact from $name


Name : $name
Email : $email
File : $image
";
 
    // Mail headers
    $email_headers = "From:test1@gmail.com";
 
    // Main messages
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers))
        {
        echo "success";
        }
      else
        {
        
  }
  ?>
```

Name and email are send to email but uploaded file not showing in my email. In email showing upload file name only. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

mail() is an extremely basic method and does not support authentication. Additionally, you cannot send attachments through this method. However, the main problem with the method is that it cannot send emails in a loop because it opens and closes sockets every time an email is sent.

you should use swift mailer instead. You can take a look at this easy tutorial 
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-send-emails-using-swift-mailer

Answer (score 0):

First of all use enctype to upload binary data file to server

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: i add enctype="multipart/form-data" but file not send to email.

Comment: you also need to add file to mail attachment this link will fix your problem http://www.tutdepot.com/php-e-mail-attachment-script/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code..this is a example code for sending mail with attachment.......

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file= $target_dir .time().basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']); 
$movefile=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
    $username=$_POST['Name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $website=$_POST['website'];
    $comments=$_POST['comments'];

$to = "receiver@gmail.com";
$subject= "Mail from";

  $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

         $headers = "From:<example@gmail.com>"."\r\n" .
         "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

         $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            "Contact Details"."\n".
         "Name :". $_POST['Name']."\n".


"\n\n";

         foreach($_FILES as $userfile)
         {
            $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
            $type = $userfile['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];
            $name = $userfile['name'];
            $size = $userfile['size'];

            if (file_exists($tmp_name))
            {
               if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
               {
                  $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

                  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

                  fclose($file);


                  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
               }

               $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                  "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                  " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                  " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
               $data . "\n\n";
            }
         }

         $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
   echo "<script>alert('Mail sent Successfully');</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location = 'contact.php';</script>";

        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Mail Not Send');</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location = 'contact.php';</script>";


        } 

?>
```